# How to get user's menu that has active modules in Laravel 4 with Eloquent?

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I have tables to store user's menu like below:

**Table: modules**

- id
- name
- status (will have values: active / inactive)

**Table: menus**

- id
- module_id
- link

**Table: menu_user**

- user_id
- menu_id
- join

**Table: users**

- id
- name
- password

The relationship will be like:

`[users]`-`<menu_user>`-`[menus]`-`[modules]`

Modules has many Menus; and relationship between Users and Menus is many to many.

I only can get user's menu:

```
$data = User::with('menus')->where('id', 2);
```

Any how with Eloquent way that I want to have the users's menu where the modules has active status?

Comment: Well, I find that seems this one fits my needs:

        $data = Module::with(['menus' => function ($q) {
            $q->join('menu_user', 'menus.id', '=', 'menu_user.menu_id')
                ->where('join', 'include')
                ->where('user_id', 2);
        }])->where('status', 'active');

maybe others can improve or had better answers are welcome.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to come from the User end and use a nested relationship to the module, eg.

```
User::where('users.id', 1)
           ->with(array('menus.module' => function($query) {
                   $query->where('modules.status', '=', 'active');
                })
            )->get();
```

This is dependent on the following in the Models:

User

```
public function menus()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Menu');
}
```

Menu

```
public function module(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Module');
}
```

Module

```
public function menu(){
    return $this->hasMany('Menu');
}
```

Glen